# How to use multiple layers in ConvLSTM model

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network, lstm

I like to check my model using multiple layers of ConvLSTM model. Shape of my training data is

```
trainX.shape (5000, 200, 4) # testX.shape (2627, 200, 4)
```

Following is my code that works fine

```
print('trainX.shape', trainX.shape) # trainX.shape (5000, 200, 4)
print('testX.shape', testX.shape) #  testX.shape (2627, 200, 4)
# reshape into subsequences (samples, time steps, rows, cols, channels)
samples, n_features = trainX.shape[0], trainX.shape[2]
n_steps, n_length = 8, 25
trainX = trainX.reshape((samples, n_steps, 1, n_length, n_features)) # 
print('trainX.shape', trainX.shape) # (5000, 8, 1, 25, 4)
testX = testX.reshape((testX.shape[0], n_steps, 1, n_length, n_features))
print('testX.shape', testX.shape) # (2627, 8, 1, 25, 4)

# define model
model = Sequential()
model.add(ConvLSTM2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(1,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(n_steps, 1, n_length, n_features)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(n_outputs, activation='softmax'))   

print(model.summary())
```

Whey I try to add another convlstm2d layer, it gives an error. I thought when we add another layer, there is no need to input shape. Following is the code I use to add another layer.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(ConvLSTM2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(1,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(n_steps, 1, n_length, n_features)))
model.add(ConvLSTM2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(1,3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(n_outputs, activation='softmax'))
```

I get following Value error.

```
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv_lst_m2d_11: expected ndim=5, found ndim=4
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a ConvLSTM(), the input shape to your neural network must be in the form `[samples, timesteps, rows, columns, features]`.

I can see that you correctly input the data to your ConvLSTM.

Try using `return_sequences = True` in the first `ConvLSTM2D()` and `return_sequences = False` in the `second ConvLSTM2D()` layer.

Comment: Yes it works, can you please give me explanation why use return_sequences parameter

Comment: The return_sequences returns the hidden state output for each input time step. If set to false, in Keras it returns only the last hidden state output. When using stacked LSTMs(standard LSTMs), you need to set return_sequences to True so that the next LSTM has a 3-D input.

Comment: simple explanation i found from this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52921819/why-in-convlstm-when-setting-return-sequence-false-you-get-an-error,
When you set the parameter return_sequence = False, only one vector is returned after that, which does not satisfy the input dimension requirements of the next layer. This causes the program not to run. When you select true, a sequence is returned so that your timestep dimension does not disappear.